# vertical align is not applied?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a `Div` which has `display:table`

[**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/IdOFUmi/5/edit)

[image]

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   <input type="checkbox" class="b"  />
   <span class="c" >aaa bbb ccc</span>
  </div>
```

And this css :

```
.wrapper
{
  display: table; 
  border:solid 1px red;
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
}

.b
{
 border:solid 1px green;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle; 
}

.c
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

As you can see - Both `.b` and `.c` has `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`

**Question**

Why does the `checkbox` is not aligned vertically while the `span` is ?

**NB**

*I know I can use padding etc to manually alignt the checkbox. But Im looking for the solution with table-cell and vertical align ( which should work)*

Comment: Try adding `height: 40px` to `.b` or even `height: 100%`

Comment: It doesn't work because checkbox is a replaced element and giving a checkbox `display: table-cell` won't work. Wrap it in a `span` and be done with it. http://jsbin.com/IdOFUmi/18/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @thirtydot You make a good point about the checkbox being a replaced element, but why does my answer work when I inherit the height?

Comment: @MarcAudet: setting `height` as `inherit` or `100%` or `40px` (basically the same as parent) all the three work for me. (not an answer for your question to thirtydot. just a mention)

Comment: @MarcAudet: That's what happens in most browsers when you give a checkbox a fixed height. Keeping it simple: http://jsbin.com/IdOFUmi/25/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @thirtydot Am I blind or that the checkbox is not 100% centered ?

Comment: It's perhaps one pixel out in my Chrome. Your Chrome has a different style of checkbox which perhaps doesn't get centered perfectly. I guess it's time for me to restart Chrome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit the height from your table down to your table cells:

```
.wrapper
{
  display: table; 
  border:solid 1px red;
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
}
.b
{ 
  border:solid 1px green;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  height: inherit;
}
.c
{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  height: inherit;
}
```

**See demo at** http://jsbin.com/IdOFUmi/23/edit

The reason is that `input` elements don't quite behave the same as other inline elements.  For some reason, setting a height to the table cell fixes the problem.

The best explanation that I can offer is based on my reading about the CSS Table model
and the generation of missing table elements:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

In this case, the `input` element, being a replaced element, cannot be a table cell.  As a result, an anonymous table-cell wrapper is generated internally by the CSS engine.

However, the anonymous table-cell does not seem to recognize the the height of the parent table.

If there is a height specified on the element, then the anonymous table-cell applies it.

The best of evidence for this explanation is that the following CSS also gives the same result:

```
.b
{ 
  border:solid 1px green;
  /* display: table-cell; OMIT THIS */
  vertical-align: middle; 
  height: inherit;
}
```

without the explicit `display: table-cell` property, the anonymous element will be drawn and the height property is needed to get the vertical alignment to work.

Comment: `inherit` has been around for ever, so that should work.  However, `display: table{-cell}` only works for IE8+

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.wrapper
{
  display: table-cell;
  border:solid 1px red;
  height:40px;
  width:200px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.b
{  
  border:solid 1px green;
}

div span
{
  border:solid 1px gray;
}
```

Working: http://jsbin.com/IdOFUmi/11/edit

You're actually want that `.wrapper` will behave as `table-cell` , in this case it will be possible to place its children in the center.

Comment: I thought that the wrapper should act like the table and the 2 divs (inner divs) should act like TD and TD

Comment: @RoyiNamir `input` doesn't have inner children , so it simply not possible to be table cell..

Comment: @RoyiNamir and i've checked it in IE10 , FF and Chrome - it's working fine ;)

Comment: I was able to get the `input` element to center vertically once I inherited the table height from the parent element.  Your comment about `input` elements not having children is true but I am not sure how this explains why my solution works.

Comment: @MarcAudet but mine is more compact ;)

Comment: @Cherniv Am I blind or that the checkbox is not 100% centered ?

Comment: @Cherniv is there a way to handle it ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir i'll try to find a solution later